# Radio/Checkboxes not saving to db

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, checkbox, radio-button

I have this form in a foreach loop, so it shows multiple times on the same page.

Everything submits fine in each form EXCEPT the radio buttons and checkboxes.  They don't save the values to the db.

**EDIT: I've narrowed it down to the ajax causing the error but can't figure out how to correct it.**

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" name="editInvoice'.$invoice_id.'" id="editInvoiceForm'.$invoice_id.'" class="editInvoiceForm edit_invoice_container" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form_item_row">
<input type="radio" value="Unsent" '.$unsent.' name="status"/><span class="choice">Unsent</span>
<input type="radio" value="Sent" '.$sent.' name="status"/><span class="choice">Sent</span>
<input type="radio" value="Paid" '.$paid.' name="status"/><span class="choice">Paid</span>          
</div>          
<div class="form_item_row">
<label for="include_timelog'.$invoice_id.'">Include Time Log</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="true" '.$include_timelog.' name="include_timelog" id="include_timelog'.$invoice_id.'" />
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>               
<div class="form_item_row_btns">
<input type="hidden" value="'.$invoice_id.'" name="hiddenInvoiceID"/>
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Update Invoice" name="action"/>
</div>
</form>
```

---

```
$query = "UPDATE invoices SET status = ".$db->prep($_POST['status']).", include_timelog = ".$db->prep((isset($_POST['include_timelog'])?1:0))." WHERE invoice_id = ".$db->prep($invoice_id);
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function()
{       
        var action = '';

        $(".due_date").datepicker();

        $('input[name=action]').click(function(){
            action = $(this).val();
        });

        $(".editInvoiceForm").submit(function() {
            $('.editInvoiceForm .form_message').html('<img src="images/loadingAnimation.gif" alt="loadingAnimation" width="30" height="8"/>');

            var dataToSend = {};
            $(this).find(':input').each(function (i,el) {
                dataToSend[el.name] = $(el).val();
            });

            dataToSend.action = action;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process.php",
                data: dataToSend,
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    //console.log(data.status);
                    if(data.status == 'error'){
                        $('.editInvoiceForm .form_message').removeClass('status_green').addClass('status_red').html(data.message).append(data.script);
                    }else{
                        $('.editInvoiceForm .form_message').removeClass('status_red').addClass('status_green').html(data.message).append(data.script);

                    }

                }
            });
            return false;
        });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need quotes around the value for status in your SQL since the value is a string.  Your include_timelog and invoice_id values are integers and do not need quotes.

```
$query = "UPDATE invoices SET status = '".$db->prep($_POST['status'])."', include_timelog = ".$db->prep((isset($_POST['include_timelog'])?1:0))." WHERE invoice_id = ".$db->prep($invoice_id);
```

Comment: Nope, didn't make a difference.  Even if I test it with only the checkbox in the form it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you update your question with a few things: 1) copy and paste the result of print_r($query)?  2) The code for $db->prep.  3) What is the value of unsent, sent, paid variables in the radio box tags?